# Sonar broken after updating: "The plugins 'findbugs' and 'java' must have exactly the same version as they belong to the same group."

Tags: sonarqube

The sonar instance on ubuntu 12.1 is broken since i upgraded to the latest version (via apt-get upgrade). The Web-UI is not accessable, and returns a 503:

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    Service Unavailable
Powered by Jetty://
```

And here is the error log:

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/10/24 08:56:11 | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/10/24 08:56:11 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:12 | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:12 |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:12 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:12 | 2013-10-24 08:56:12.314:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.6.11.v20130520
2013.10.24 08:56:14 INFO  o.s.s.p.ServerImpl  SonarQube Server / 3.7.3 / b241d9e47bbe7694cbe7574817240cef214fd316
2013.10.24 08:56:14 INFO  o.s.c.p.Database  Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
2013.10.24 08:56:16 INFO  o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem  SonarQube home: /opt/sonar
2013.10.24 08:56:16 INFO  o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem  Deploy dir: /opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/deploy
2013.10.24 08:56:16 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Install plugins...
2013.10.24 08:56:16 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Findbugs / 1.3 / 4d7d78e9340e39f53bbf202ed16d1253e6507c36
2013.10.24 08:56:16 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin JaCoCo / 1.4 / a4f903a3386ed8611cfd2cb9ef4d8e60ca32bff1
2013.10.24 08:56:16 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin English Pack / 3.7.3 / b241d9e47bbe7694cbe7574817240cef214fd316
2013.10.24 08:56:16 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin SCM Activity / 1.6 / 98fb6ca20f0829d6ead2ab029221ddd781b6e971
2013.10.24 08:56:16 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Maven Batch Plugin / 3.7.3 / b241d9e47bbe7694cbe7574817240cef214fd316
2013.10.24 08:56:16 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Surefire / 1.4 / a4f903a3386ed8611cfd2cb9ef4d8e60ca32bff1
2013.10.24 08:56:16 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Duplications / 3.7.3 / b241d9e47bbe7694cbe7574817240cef214fd316
2013.10.24 08:56:16 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Checkstyle / 1.4 / a4f903a3386ed8611cfd2cb9ef4d8e60ca32bff1
2013.10.24 08:56:16 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin PMD / 1.4 / a4f903a3386ed8611cfd2cb9ef4d8e60ca32bff1
2013.10.24 08:56:16 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Java / 1.4 / a4f903a3386ed8611cfd2cb9ef4d8e60ca32bff1
2013.10.24 08:56:16 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Core / 3.7.3 / b241d9e47bbe7694cbe7574817240cef214fd316
2013.10.24 08:56:16 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Database Cleaner / 3.7.3 / b241d9e47bbe7694cbe7574817240cef214fd316
2013.10.24 08:56:16 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Technical Debt / 1.2.1
2013.10.24 08:56:16 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Squid for Java / 1.3 / 4d7d78e9340e39f53bbf202ed16d1253e6507c36
2013.10.24 08:56:16 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Design / 3.7.3 / b241d9e47bbe7694cbe7574817240cef214fd316
2013.10.24 08:56:16 INFO  o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer  Deploy plugin Email notifications / 3.7.3 / b241d9e47bbe7694cbe7574817240cef214fd316
2013.10.24 08:56:16 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Install plugins done: 264 ms
2013.10.24 08:56:16 ERROR o.s.s.p.Platform  The plugins 'findbugs' and 'java' must have exactly the same version as they belong to the same group.
org.sonar.updatecenter.common.exception.IncompatiblePluginVersionException: The plugins 'findbugs' and 'java' must have exactly the same version as they belong to the same group.
    at org.sonar.updatecenter.common.PluginReferential.getParentRelease(PluginReferential.java:132) ~[sonar-update-center-common-1.8.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.updatecenter.common.PluginReferential.setParent(PluginReferential.java:120) ~[sonar-update-center-common-1.8.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.updatecenter.common.PluginReferentialManifestConverter.fromPluginManifests(PluginReferentialManifestConverter.java:54) ~[sonar-update-center-common-1.8.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.plugins.PluginReferentialMetadataConverter.getInstalledPluginReferential(PluginReferentialMetadataConverter.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.sonar.server.plugins.InstalledPluginReferentialFactory.init(InstalledPluginReferentialFactory.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.sonar.server.plugins.InstalledPluginReferentialFactory.start(InstalledPluginReferentialFactory.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91) ~[sonar-plugin-api-3.7.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startDatabaseConnectors(Platform.java:251) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:189) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(PlatformLifecycleListener.java:33) [classes/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:746) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:238) [jetty-servlet-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1240) [jetty-webapp-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:689) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:482) [jetty-webapp-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:281) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
    at org.sonar.application.JettyEmbedder.start(JettyEmbedder.java:67) [sonar-application-3.7.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.application.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:48) [sonar-application-3.7.3.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240) [wrapper-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [na:1.6.0_27]
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at org.sonar.updatecenter.common.Artifact.getRelease(Artifact.java:68) ~[sonar-update-center-common-1.8.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.updatecenter.common.PluginReferential.getParentRelease(PluginReferential.java:130) ~[sonar-update-center-common-1.8.jar:na]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 | 2013-10-24 08:56:16.508:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server/},file:/opt/sonar/war/sonar-server
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 | org.sonar.updatecenter.common.exception.IncompatiblePluginVersionException: The plugins 'findbugs' and 'java' must have exactly the same version as they belong to the same group.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.updatecenter.common.PluginReferential.getParentRelease(PluginReferential.java:132)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.updatecenter.common.PluginReferential.setParent(PluginReferential.java:120)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.updatecenter.common.PluginReferentialManifestConverter.fromPluginManifests(PluginReferentialManifestConverter.java:54)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.server.plugins.PluginReferentialMetadataConverter.getInstalledPluginReferential(PluginReferentialMetadataConverter.java:40)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.server.plugins.InstalledPluginReferentialFactory.init(InstalledPluginReferentialFactory.java:48)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.server.plugins.InstalledPluginReferentialFactory.start(InstalledPluginReferentialFactory.java:37)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startDatabaseConnectors(Platform.java:251)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:189)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(PlatformLifecycleListener.java:33)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:746)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:238)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1240)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:689)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:482)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:281)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.application.JettyEmbedder.start(JettyEmbedder.java:67)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.application.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:48)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 | Caused by: 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 | java.util.NoSuchElementException
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.updatecenter.common.Artifact.getRelease(Artifact.java:68)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.updatecenter.common.PluginReferential.getParentRelease(PluginReferential.java:130)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.updatecenter.common.PluginReferential.setParent(PluginReferential.java:120)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.updatecenter.common.PluginReferentialManifestConverter.fromPluginManifests(PluginReferentialManifestConverter.java:54)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.server.plugins.PluginReferentialMetadataConverter.getInstalledPluginReferential(PluginReferentialMetadataConverter.java:40)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.server.plugins.InstalledPluginReferentialFactory.init(InstalledPluginReferentialFactory.java:48)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.server.plugins.InstalledPluginReferentialFactory.start(InstalledPluginReferentialFactory.java:37)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startDatabaseConnectors(Platform.java:251)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:189)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(PlatformLifecycleListener.java:33)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:746)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:238)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1240)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:689)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:482)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:281)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.application.JettyEmbedder.start(JettyEmbedder.java:67)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.sonar.application.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:48)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/10/24 08:56:16 | 2013-10-24 08:56:16.533:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9000
```

What i've tried:

Updating the packages in the plugins folder, to the latest from [Sonar Ecosystem](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Java+Ecosystem) no they were all sonar-*-1.4.jar

How can i update the findbugs and java plugin without accessing sonar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After updating the

```
/opt/sonar/extensions/plugins
```

directory with the jars from the [SonarEcosystem](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Java+Ecosystem), make sure permissions are correct, in my case:

```
ls -lsa
44 -rw-r--r-- 1 sonar adm   44212 Oct 24 09:34 sonar-java-plugin-1.4.jar
```

when restarting, ensure that you wait till sonar is up:

```
 tail -f /opt/sonar/logs/sonar.log
```

Comment: do you mean to download the javaEcosystem-1.5.zip and manually extract it to the directory? I did that and it worked

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the new 2.4 Java plugin, you can remove the Squid, Surefire and Jacoco plugins. They're now all rolled into one plugin:

[http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Java+Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Java+Plugin)

> Version 2.4 moves Java from being an "ecosystem" of multiple plugins
>   to a single, stand-alone plugin that encompasses most of the
>   functionality formerly contained in the ecosystem. Specifically, 
>   Squid, Surefire and Jacoco have been rolled into the Java plugin.
>   FindBugs has been split off into an independent, optional plugin. To
>   continue using it, upgrade it to version 2.4. Unfortunately,
>   SonarQube's update center cannot handle the switch gracefully. You may
>   use the update center to download the new version of the plugin.
>   However, you must manually remove the Surefire, JaCoCo, and Squid for
>   Java plugins from$SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugins.

To fix the problem of versions with 2.4, Squid, Surefire and Jacoco need to be **removed**.

Answer (score 4):

Following the directions in bold from the [plugin doc](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Java+Plugin):

> Upgrade to 2.4 You CANNOT upgrade automatically to 2.4 Version 2.4
>   moves Java from being an "ecosystem" of multiple plugins to a single,
>   stand-alone plugin that encompasses most of the functionality formerly
>   contained in the ecosystem. Specifically,  Squid, Surefire and Jacoco
>   have been rolled into the Java plugin. FindBugs has been split off
>   into an independent, optional plugin. To continue using it, upgrade it
>   to version 2.4. Unfortunately, SonarQube's update center cannot handle
>   the switch gracefully. You may use the update center to download the
>   new version of the plugin. However, **you must manually remove the
>   Surefire, JaCoCo, and Squid for Java plugins
>   from$SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugins.**

```
rm /opt/sonar/extensions/plugins/sonar-surefire-plugin-*
rm /opt/sonar/extensions/plugins/sonar-jacoco-plugin-*
rm /opt/sonar/extensions/plugins/sonar-squid-plugin-*
```

Comment: I also needed to remove `extensions/plugins/sonar-findbugs-plugin-2.0.jar`